# Prove: if A and B are invertible matrixes, then AB is veritable

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to prove that. 
My method is,
$A$,$b$ are invertible
so, $\det(A)!= 0$ and $\det(B)!= 0$
so, $\det(AB) = \det(A)+\det(B)$;
$\det(AB) != 0$,
so they AB are invertible.

I think my method is false.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Be careful.  It is not true that $\det (AB)=\det (A)+\det (B)$.

Comment: There is no need to mess around with determinants. What does it mean for a matrix to be invertible?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\det(AB) = \det(A)\cdot \det(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible, then by the very definition of invertible $AX=I$ for some $X~ (=A^{-1})$.  Similarly, if $B$ is invertible, then by the very definition of invertible $BY=I$ for some $Y~(=B^{-1})$.

Then $(AB)(YX)=A(BY)X=AIX=AX=I$, so $AB$ is invertible and its inverse is $YX$ (normally denoted as $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$).

Comment: Given how confused the OP appears to be, it might be worth mentioning that one needs to check as well that $(YX)(AB) = I$, though the calculation is similar. (I am, of course, aware that matrix rings over a field are Dedekind finite, but there is no need to appeal to this when there is an easy explicit approach.)